ssh connection (2 hops)
I'm not sure how to formulate my question in a title format, that's why I can't google it normally, but basically what I need to do is the following,
I have a work laptop which I use to connect to work jump-server,
ssh name@jump -D1234
then I'm using a password to authenticate and continue from that jump server to all work related services.
When I'm trying to connect via ssh to my laptop, which is working fine, and then ssh to jump, it says  Permission denied (publickey)
From what I've understood, when connecting via ssh and regular from laptop, it's considering this like another user.
Can you please advise how I can resolve this issue?
Thanks



Can you try to connect with the -v option in both cases and add the output to the question? (Preferably copy it as text, not as image...)

Hi! thanks for your reply!
Here is the differences
Laptop(working)
debug1: Offering public key: maxim@maxim-HP-ProBook-440-G4 RSA SHA256:fQAvCXwkol3CuoPtAwxR99SlV7OkYxC/0PO1Urx1A8k agent
debug1: Server accepts key: maxim@maxim-HP-ProBook-440-G4 RSA SHA256:fQAvCXwkol3CuoPtAwxR99SlV7OkYxC/0PO1Urx1A8k agent
Authenticated using "publickey" with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
maxim.ag@10.11.12.1's password:

ssh from my PC to laptop and than ssh to jump(not working)
debug1: Trying private key: /home/maxim/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/maxim/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/maxim/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/maxim/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/maxim/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/maxim/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /home/maxim/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
maxim.ag@10.11.12.1: Permission denied (publickey).

Just some related ideas: Maybe SSH agent forwarding is of interest. You could also try the “native” jumphost (-J) functionality with OpenSSH. // What are the operating systems involved?

Your server is set up to require both password and public-key authentication. Your laptop's GUI environment likely has SSH_AUTH_SOCK set to the path of a (preconfigured) ssh-agent to provide the key, allowing ssh to proceed to the password prompt.
Find the value from printenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK in a local session, then export the same value when connecting via SSH (or set it through ~/.bashrc, or through ~/.ssh/config "IdentityAgent").

It worked! Thank you so much!
